# How to remove literal symbol characters from lines starts with particular words on notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to remove literal symbol characters (-,‧,#)  from lines starts with particular words and ending with / symbol.

From:

```
==== vi‧o#late / ...
```

To:

```
==== violate / ...
```

I have tried the following
From:

```
^[\Q==== \E].*
```

To:

But that regex cannot find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(^==== |\G)(\w+)[^\w\s]+`
- Replace with: `$1$2`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(^==== |\G) # group 1, line that start with ==== or restart match from the last match position
(\w+)       # group 2, 1 or more word character
[^\w\s]+    # 1 or more any character that is not a word character or a space
```

**Result for given example:**

```
==== violate / ...
```

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but it converts "vi‧o‧late /ˈvaɪəleɪt/ ●○○ AWL verb [transitive]" to "late /ˈvaɪəleɪt/ ●○○ AWL verb [transitive]" it loses "vio" characters from output.